# While loop exits unexpectedly

Tags: python, binary-search

In this sample code, I tried to perform binary search for n times

The problem is that, the while loop exits on its first iteration, although **l < r** condition is still applied!

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; n = 5
for i in range (n) :
    l = 0; r = n - 1; init = arr[l]; x = 5
    while l < r :
        mid = (r - l) // 2
        if init + arr[mid] > x :
            r = mid
        elif init + arr[mid] < x :
            l = mid
```

Why this behavior happened?

Comment: Did you already debug the code, i.e. execute it line by line and check the content of variables? If not that would be the way to go here.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Yes. I tried to debug it, but I couldn't figure out the source of the problem

Comment: You have an infinite loop, not one which is stopping without a reason. It simply isn't true that the code that you posted works like you say it does.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

The link is too long to put in a comment so I'll post an answer.

[Try running this in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=arr%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203,%204,%205%5D%3B%20n%20%3D%205%0Afor%20i%20in%20range%20%28n%29%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20l%20%3D%200%3B%20r%20%3D%20n%20-%201%3B%20init%20%3D%20arr%5Bl%5D%3B%20x%20%3D%205%0A%20%20%20%20while%20l%20%3C%20r%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mid%20%3D%20%28r%20-%20l%29%20//%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20init%20%2B%20arr%5Bmid%5D%20%3E%20x%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%20%3D%20mid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20elif%20init%20%2B%20arr%5Bmid%5D%20%3C%20x%20%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20l%20%3D%20mid&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

This will let you step through the code and see what the value of the variables are at each step. You will notice when you run it that it truncates the execution at 1000 steps so your code definitely doesn't break the loop unexpectedly and instead goes infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop because you did not use any `break` statement in anywhere of your code, so it continues forever.

Second, your code needed some modifications. We do not use `;` in Python to separate codes, but we separate codes in new lines.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    ll = 0
    r = n - 1
    init = arr[ll]
    x = 5
    while ll < r:
        mid = (r - ll) // 2
        if init + arr[mid] > x:
            r = mid
            print(f'this is r: {r}')
            break
        elif init + arr[mid] < x:
            ll = mid
            print(f'this is ll: {ll}')
            break
```

This is modified version of your code, so we could debug it better. I usually use `print` statement to debug my code whenever I want to check what's wrong with it, something you did not put it in your code.

This is the output of your code:

```
this is ll: 2
this is ll: 2
this is ll: 2
this is ll: 2
this is ll: 2
```